# Sum of Measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

The proofs for , "if $f,g :X\to \mathbb{R}$ are integrable then $f+g$ is (Lebesgue) measurable" is available in any Real Analysis textbook.

$\textbf{BUT}$ I have a doubt about it  and also the proof if we assume that $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$  and $g :Y\to \mathbb{R}$. Does it make any difference?

My guess is no and still we can write the proof for $f(x)+g(y)$ is measurable iff the following set is (Lebesgue) measurable: (for a fixed $t$)
$$\{(x,y)\in X \times Y\ s.t. f(x)+g(y)> t \} = \bigcup_{r,q\in \mathbb{Q} \\ r+q > t} \big[\{(x,y)\in X\times Y  | f(x)>q \}\cap \{(x,y)\in X \times Y | g(y)>r    \} \big]$$

Is above true?

Comment: How are you defining $f+g$ if $f$ and $g$ don't have the same domain? Also, your proof appears to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of $\mathbb R$. Is this assumption valid?

Comment: There is no gain in generality in assuming that $f$ and $g$ are defined on different domains, so I think you will only increase confusion by adding that detail.

Comment: About the assumption, I agree and just edited. 
but for the other , can't we look at it like we want to show that $h(x,y) = f(x) + g(y)$ is measurable?

Comment: It only makes sense to consider $f+g$ on $X\cap Y$, otherwise how do you plan on adding them together if one isn't defined where the other is?

Comment: so you mean that if I write $h(x,y) = f(x)+g(y)$ to be defined on $X\times Y$ above proof does not make sense or it just makes sense if $h$ is defined on $X\cap Y$?

Comment: @stat $X \cap Y$ is not a subset of $X \times Y$. If addition is restricted to $X \cap Y$, then the domain of definition of $h$ would be $(X \cap Y) \times (X \cap Y)$.